# Calculate Percent Increase When an Increase is Indicated By Smaller Number?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure why I can't wrap my head around this. If I am profiling the runtime of a web application I am developing and lets say the average is 1000ms. Then after some refactoring and optimization, the average runtime is only 200ms.

How do I calculate the percentage of performance gain? Obviously it's an 80% difference but the performance gain should be something over 100% correct? How would I calculate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance could be viewed as the number of operations per unit time. Let us take as unit of time say $1$ second (it doesn't matter, as long as we are consistent). Then the old result was $1$, the new result is $5$, for a performance gain of $400\%$.

Comment: Great! I knew it had to be simple.

Answer (score 2):

it is runing 5 times faster (1000/200), therefore the performance gain is $+400\%$.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, makes perfect sense.